# webcam and microphone access in ec2 instance amazon

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud

I want to use my webcam and microphone in my ec2 instance but it allows camera not found , same issue for the microphone is there any way to give access to webcam and microphone in ec2 instance so that I can use my webcam and microphone within the server ( i am running windows base 2019 server).

Comment: How do you exactly expect to connect your microphone and camera to physical servers in AWS data centers?

Answer (score 1):

From the description of your requirements, Amazon EC2 would not be an appropriate service for you to use.

If you wish to have "remove desktop" capabilities, then [Amazon WorkSpaces](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/latest/adminguide/amazon-workspaces.html) would be a more-appropriate service.